# Deleting timeline activity from FB

Tags: facebook, firefox-addon, imacros

I am trying to use iMacro to delete my FB timeline activity.  I can easily record one action such as delete, hide, or unlike, but on my timeline these actions are interwined and thus the macro breaks down when I do a loop to, for example, delete activity.

Is there a way that the macro can check which type of post it is and then take the appropriate action.

For example:

```
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/myusername/allactivity?privacy_source=privacy_settings_page
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:mrs<SP>_2fmu<SP>customimg<SP>img<SP>sp_8g08g1<SP>sx_8e1c65&&TXT:
If option is to unlike then:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Unlike
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=NAME:ok&&VALUE:Unlike
If option is to delete then:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:mrs<SP>_2fmu<SP>customimg<SP>img<SP>sp_8g08g1<SP>sx_8e1c65&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Delete
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=CLASS:uiButton<SP>uiButtonLarge<SP>uiButtonConfirm&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=CLASS:uiButton<SP>uiButtonLarge<SP>uiButtonConfirm&&TXT:
If option is to hide then:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:_2fmu<SP>img<SP>sp_8g08g1<SP>sx_8e1c65<SP>customimg&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Hidden<SP>from<SP>Timeline
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:u_13_2 ATTR=ID:u_13_1
```

An alternative would be to do the first round of just (i.e.)deletes and the macro would just skip is that is not the action to be taken.  Or open to any other solutions to deleting timeline data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```

and it will not stop the macro on error, other than that you'll need to convert your script to javascript format (or similar) to implement real IF statement procedures

Comment: can the iMcros run javascript instead of whatever language I used above? Can they be intermingled?

Comment: imacros has limited ability to run javascript code using URL GOTO command or using EVAL, but to run different parts of code depending on condition you need to convert your script to javascript or similar